# syntax error "SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'else'" for JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax-error

Hello I'm learning JavaScript currently at Codecademy and I am up to the paper scissors rock game, though I am getting an error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'else'
```

here is my code, thnx! :)

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
    if(choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return ("The result is a tie");
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock")
    {
        if(choice2 === "scissors")
        return ("rock wins");
    }
    else
    {
        return ("paper wins");
    }
    else if(choice1 === "paper")
    {
        if(choice2 === "rock")
        return ("paper wins");
    }
    else
    {
        return ("scissors wins");
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't have else if after else

Comment: `else` block should always be the last block in `if else if` ladder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no condition of if in the 2nd else.. Either put a condition based on your logic or in order to run this..here is what you can do

Instead of checking using nested `if`, you can do it like

```
  if( condition1 && condition2){ // logic
```

Here is how you won't get error.

```
    var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
    {
        if(choice1 === choice2)
        {
            return ("The result is a tie");
        }
        else if(choice1 === "rock")
        {
            if(choice2 === "scissors")
            return ("rock wins");
        }
        else
        {
            return ("paper wins");
        }

        if(choice1 === "paper")
        {
            if(choice2 === "rock")
            return ("paper wins");
        }
        else
        {
            return ("scissors wins");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why bother having elses after a return?

Comment: @mplungjan agreed. I just fixed the syntax error.. didn't change the logic..There can be a number of optimizations though :)

Comment: Are we not missing a comparison or am I just not awake enough? https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/24kv4azz/

Comment: again .. @mplungjan I am not concerned with the logic here.I just gave him the hint of his syntax error,,,yes, he needs to check it and change it..

Comment: That is only half the answer then. If I am correct, that should be pointed out if noticed in my opinion

Comment: He meant syntax error, you are right, I fixed syntax error irrespective of logic which I really won't look at since I don't know his requirements @mplungjan

Comment: Haha - his requirement is to return a correct comparison between rock, paper and scissors :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, error messages are surprisingly helpful if you actually read them a couple of times. Most systems will also tell you the line on which the error occurred, or even jump to that point in the code for you. In this case, you have a pretty clear message saying "Unexpected keyword 'else'”, and I assume you know the line. From there, it should be pretty straightforward to figure out the problem.

If you can't, a typical approach is to REMOVE things until the error goes away--then you know that the last thing you removed is what caused the error.